# What is a good stabilizer for Y axis?

Tags: stabilisation

I'm sorry, if it's not the right place to ask this question.

I have tested many times the Zhiyun crane 3 lab camera stabilizer. It really works well except for the Y axis...

If you use it while walking, you clearly see the steps movement in the shot. Also sometimes it hard to move the camera in any direction freely.

Does anyone know any good professionnal solution for image stabilization ? I wish I had an Arri Trinity but... my budget is around 2000-3000€.

I'm open to any technology as long as it works and you can have a free movement.

My camera is a Blackmagic URSA Mini Pro 4.6K G2 and I mount an Atomos Ninja on the stabilizer.

Thanks.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

A 3-axis gimbal can reduce rotation but not translation - ie it will twist in 3 axis to smooth the motion, but it can't physically move to account for your movement up and down.

I think there are three ways to resolve this:

Use a [body mounted stabiliser](https://glidecam.com/product-category/products/body-mounted-stabilizers/) that compensates for movement.  These are expensive and cumbersome, but they work. They also reduce arm strain as the weight of the camera is taken by the body straps.

Practice compensating for the movement yourself. The best way to imagine this is to move as though you were carrying a hot drink instead of a camera. This is free, but requires some time to practice.

Shoot at a higher resolution than you need to deliver, then use digital stabilisation to try and improve your video.  This works to some extent, but any motion blur due to camera movement will still be visible, depending on the shutter & frame rate you shoot at.